# Partitioning the table

Tags: database, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

This query is regarding partitioning in hive/delta tables.

Which column should we pick for partitioning the table if the table is always being used to join based on key which have only unique value.
Ex: we have a table Customer(id, name, otherDetails)
which field be suitable to partition this table.

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Below are factors you need to consider while partitioning -

1. **Requirement** - when you have lots of data, heavily used table, frequently data added to it, and you want to manage it better.
2. **Distribution of data** - choose a field or fields on which data is evenly distributed. Most common is date or month or year, and normally transactional data is somewhat evenly distributed on these fields. You can choose something like country or region as well to partition when you have data evenly distributed.
3. **Loading strategy** - You can load/insert/delete each partition separately. So choose some columns which will help you deciding a better strategy. Like you can choose to delete old data based on date every time you load. so chose load date as partition.
4. **Reasonable number of partitions** - Make sure you do not have thousands of partitions but less that 500 is good ( check your systems performance).
5. **Do not choose** unique key/composite key as partition key. because hive creates folders with data files for each partition and it will be very difficult to manage thousands of partitions.